# PhpStorm structural searching to find a self-assignment in a foreach loop

Tags: php, phpstorm, structural-search

I have noticed a pattern among some of my team's developers where we will do a self-assignment of an array in a foreach loop, and I am looking for the proper search parameters to pass into PhpStorm's structural search to match the first workflow, but not the second in the following example:

```php
public function example()
{
    $array = [];
    foreach ($array as $a) {
       $array[$a] = 1; //Match this one
    }

    $someOtherVariable = [];
    foreach($array as $ab) {
        $someOtherVariable[] = 2; //Don't match this one
    }
}
```

The basic structural search `foreach($c$){$c$}` matches them both, and I cannot figure out if there is a filter to apply to the variable `$c$` such that the interior variable is detected to be the same as the inherited loop variable.

Comment: I may suggest contacting JetBrains support (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731): they better know how their product works for such specific functionality. I did my own testing but could not figure it out as well... I'm interested to know the possible solution for this as well.

Comment: Looks like a bug accordingly to PhpStorm devs: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54244